# "последствие" vs "следствие"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Мне наплевать на **последствия**.
>
> vs: Мне наплевать на **следствия**.

On the surface, they both seem to mean "consequence", the sense presumably originating from the word "след/track/footprint".

I wonder why in this specific instance, "последствие" with the prefix "по-" is the one to go for? Why does the use of "следствие" sound odd here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Следствие** often (though not always) has *neutral* meaning as in '*cause - effect*' pair (**причина - следствие**), while **последствия(-е)** is typically about something *negative*, like *delayed bad results* from some event/action (**событие/действие - последствия**).

Answer (score 5):

`Следствие` (singular) is widely used in the math in the meaning of `effect` / `consequence`, like in a logical pair `cause` - `effect`, and also in the meaning of `investigation` (criminal).
The word `следствия` is either a plural form or genitive of `следствие`.

The word `последствие` has a very close (if not the same) meaning `result` / `effect` / `aftermath` / `consequence`. But in some circumstances it has a negative connotation. For instance:

> Последствия пожара
>   Последствия болезни

Also it makes sense to mention a preposition `вследствие` which has a meaning `as a consequence of`.

Comment: The question is about the word следстви**я**, not следстви**е**.

Comment: @AviGordon Word `следствия` is a plural form of the word `следствие`. Isn't it?

Comment: If it's criminal investigation then it's one the meanings, but not really the most popular. As far I as see следствие (what follows) and следствие (criiminal investigation) are homonyms.

Comment: @Dmitry: `следствие` as "criminal investigation" does not have a plural form.

Comment: @AviGordon Maybe you are right. But I'm not completely sure whether `ведутся следствия` sounds weird or not. Nevertheless, the word `следствия` could be used as "criminal investigation" in genitive: `в рамках следствия`, `до начала следствия` etc. Anyway, I've improved the answer, thank you.

Comment: @Dmitry, the Genitive, I'm afraid, is irrelevant as the words in the question are in Accusative. :)
It's not what does or does not sound weird to us. It's what is or is not registered by contemporary dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

**Последствие** is a thing or event that starts/happens at some point in time.

*Я [не] думаю|беспокоюсь о последствиях* - I [don't] think|care about what can happen [because of it].

*Курение приводит к негативным последствиям: одышке и т.д.* - Smoking has negative consequences like wheeze etc.

*Дождь вызвал последствия в виде наводнения* - Rain caused the flood.

**Следствие** (in sense of *effect*, not *investigation*) is an abstract thing, which is true since its cause is true. Synonyms are **вывод**, **заключение**.

*Теорема имеет следующие следствия* (not *последствия*) - From the theorem you can draw the following corollaries.

*Следствия, которые мы можем вывести из этих фактов, таковы...* - From the facts we can conclude that ...

**But** in some set phrases (*Следствием ... является ...*) it is used instead of **последствие**.

*Следствием дождя явилось наводнение.* - The flood came as a consequence of the rain.

*Следствием курения являются заболевания легких* -  Lung diseases are caused by smoking.

You can use **последствие** here as well and it will sound only a little unusual.

Comment: In maths, _следствие_ normally means  _corollary_ not _conclusion_

Comment: @J-mster you are probably right.